# Does QGIS have support for WMS-T (WMS with time)?

Tags: geolocation, geoserver, wms, qgis

Does anyone know if there's support for WMS-T in QGIS?

Through the app I can add WMS layers, but I can't work with WMS-T (there's no place to set the time parameter).

I been going through the the Python plugins and although there are some that do work with time (Time Manager, Multi temporal and Multivariate data visualisation) they do not support the WMS protocol (they work directly with databases).

Regards

NOTE - I'm working with GeoServer

Comment: See also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34667/does-qgis-have-wms-t-wms-with-time-support  There is an awkward workaround that used WMS to get a particular WMS-T instance.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: This feature is currently under development, you can follow the progress on https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/132

---

Old: No, QGIS does not support WMS-T currently.

Your options are to improve the current WMS provider, write a plugin, sponsor development, ...

Comment: Your super-cool TimeManager plugin supports WMS-T as of 2015-07-07.